Does the equivalence principle only apply for the gravitational field of an infinitely sized body?
From my couch-level understanding of the equivalence principle it seems like unless the source of the gravitational body on that side of the equation was infinitely sized, it would be simple to measure a difference between the two as the gravitational field of a non-infinite body would always have a center while acceleration does not.
Perhaps this difference doesn't have any impact on how this principle applies to general relativity?


TIL the term "couch-level"

You have noted something really important, but there is a caveat in the formulation of the equivalence principle that avoids your remark.
The equivalence principle states that locally a gravitational field is indistinguishable from acceleration. The word locally is very important: it means you are only allowed to look at a single point at a time. You cannot look at what is happening at nearby points, so you are not allowed to probe that the gravitational field "has a center". Furthermore, this avoids the problem with tidal effects: objects closer to a mass feel a greater attraction than objects far from that mass, so for example your head and your toes are accelerating toward Earth with different accelerations. The equivalence principle does not consider these effects, because you are looking at a single point at a time.
This is a subtlety in the equivalence principle that I don't think is sufficiently appreciated. Gravity and acceleration are not equivalent at all, they are merely locally equivalent. At a single point you cannot distinguish a gravitational field from acceleration, but when you consider effects on a larger region there are things that gravity can do, but acceleration cannot.

That makes a lot of sense, a single point would always have a direct path to the center of a body so you would measure no horizontal component.

I always interpreted "local" to be in the calculus / analysis meaning of "up to some specified differential order" (e.g. first order, second order, etc.), rather than "only at a single point at a time".

@Arthur it varies a bit depending on the context. Spacetime is locally Minkowskian in the sense that it is flat to first order (i.e. the second derivatives of the metric (the curvatures) are non-vanishing, but one can always make the first derivatives (the Christoffel symbols) vanish). However, curvature introduces corrections that are not characteristic of acceleration, only of gravity, so the equivalence principle ends up holding only at a point. This can be made more rigorous by noting that you can make the Christoffel symbols vanish at a specific point, but not in a neighborhood

In my answer I took a shortcut and went straight to "holds at a point", but this follows from spacetime being locally Minkowskian in your sense and from the fact that the second derivatives being non-vanishing makes so that the Christoffel symbols only vanish at a single point

This answer is an extension to the answer posted by Níckolas Alves.
The qualification locally appears to suggest that the principle of equivalence only holds good for single points.
Of course that is not the case; it is very much the intention that the validity has intrinsic spatial extent.

The way to resolve that tension, in my opinion, is to allow the principle of equivalence to be stated in the negative.
We define 'local measurement' as an experiment that is sufficiently small such that center-of-gravity effect and tidal effect are below detection level.
If an experimental setup would exist that still measures a difference even when it's a local measurement, then the principle of equivalence concept would be invalid.


Mathematically speaking, the trick that makes the principle work as desired anyways, is the same trick that allows you to define the instantaneous speed of a car: You are not considering an interval/area/space/time of a given size, you are considering an interval/area/space/time that can be chosen to be arbitrarily small. And the smaller you make the interval/area/space/time, the smaller the error becomes, tending towards zero. Then the mathematician simply takes the limit of a sequence of intervals that tends towards zero size, and gets results with zero error.
Also note, that you can decompose the field in your drawing into a field with perfectly parallel field lines, and a second field that contains the deviation from the parallel field. The second field is basically our error. And you can choose the first field in such a way that the error field becomes zero at whatever point you choose. As such, you can subdivide your drawing into infinitesimally small cubes such that the error is infinitesimally small in all of them. And in the limit, you have no error at all.

On the page where Landau & Lifshitz (vol. 2, p. 226) introduce the equivalence principle, you find this answer to the physical question that you are asking:

However, the fields to which noninertial reference systems are
equivalent are not completely identical with “actual” gravitational
fields which occur also in inertial frames. For there is a very
essential difference with respect to their behavior at infinity. At
infinite distances from the bodies producing the field, “actual”
gravitational fields always go to zero. Contrary to this, the fields
to which noninertial frames are equivalent increase without limit at
infinity, or, in any event, remain finite in value. Thus, for example,
the centrifugal force which appears in a rotating reference system
increases without limit as we move away from the axis of rotation; the
field to which a reference system in accelerated linear motion is
equivalent is the same over all space and also at infinity.

And then continued on the next page:

The fields to which noninertial systems are equivalent vanish as soon
as we transform to an inertial system. In contrast to this, “actual”
gravitational fields (existing also in an inertial reference frame)
cannot be eliminated by any choice of reference system. This is
already clear from what has been said above concerning the difference
in conditions at infinity between “actual” gravitational fields and
fields to which noninertial systems are equivalent; since the latter
do not approach zero at infinity, it is clear that it is impossible,
by any choice of reference frame, to eliminate an “actual” field,
since it vanishes at infinity.
All that can be done by a suitable choice of reference system is to
eliminate the gravitational field in a given region of space,
sufficiently small so that the field can be considered uniform over
it. This can be done by choosing a system in accelerated motion, the
acceleration of which is equal to that which would be acquired by a
particle placed in the region of the field which we are considering.

As for the way you posed your question, you will find that thinking about parallel lines and the point where they meet is a rich and subtle question in general relativity which will lead you to consider the question of parallel transport on a curved manifold and the question what a straight line actually is: is it a geodesic? But would it be the one followed by a massive particle or that of a massless particle?

Yes, the idea of the volume, in and above, a massive spherical body increasing geometrically as an f(radius) from its CG is really interesting to me. My math is poor, but I'm working on it.
